# How to find how many POSTS (not page) has a user liked on my facebook profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is there a way to find out (or generate a count) of how many posts has a user 'liked' on my facebook profile?

For example, if I provide a userID, can I query that how many of the posts (on a particular facebook profile page) has this user liked?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) for that.

The two FQL tables that are of interest here are:

- [like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) - "returns the IDs of users who like a given object (video, note, link, photo, or album)"
- [stream](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/)  - "used to return a list of a stream posts"

You can then use them both like this:

```
SELECT 
    object_id 
FROM 
    like 
WHERE 
    user_id = USER_ID 
    AND 
    post_id IN (SELECT 
                    post_id 
                FROM 
                    stream 
                WHERE 
                    source_id = PAGE_ID)
```

You'll need to have two permissions for the logged in user when you try this: read_stream and read_insights.

You can try it in the [Graph Api Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql?q=SELECT%20object_id%20FROM%20like%20WHERE%20user_id%20=%20USER_ID%20AND%20post_id%20IN%20%28SELECT%20post_id%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20=%20PAGE_ID%29) (just replace the USER_ID and PAGE_ID with real ids)

Comment: Thanks, will try it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry about this basic question, how do one find post_ID and page_ID?

Comment: You don't need the post_id, just the USER_ID and PAGE_ID (what I wrote in caps). The page id is the id of the page profile that you want to check, it's like a user id but for a page...  For example, if you check this graph url of the [South Park page](http://graph.facebook.com/southpark) you'll see the id is "6708787004". You can do the same with your page, replace the "southpark" with the "username" of your page.