# How to list posts that the logged in user liked on my page (Facebook Graph API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.6

Is there a way to list all the posts that the logged in user has liked on my page?

I know that I can check post by post using the Graph API ("has_liked": true at summary) using this:

```
GET v2.6/POST_ID?fields=likes.summary(true).limit(0)
```

but is there a better solution?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203621/how-to-find-how-many-posts-not-page-has-a-user-liked-on-my-facebook-profile) seems to contain the solution, but it doesn't work with newer versions of the API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No there is no other solution. Why do you need to know what posts the user liked?

Comment: I would like to do some analytics based on that data, so that I could know what to show to the user when he is redirected to a news website. This would be very useful, since the interaction with the FB page is much higher than with the website (users can like the post based on the headline and do not access the website, for example).